# Interacting with elements not visible using selenium

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When implementing EndUser Login tests for my application, when logging in through LinkedIn, I get this error:
 "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with."

This error comes while executing the test suite via maven in cmd prompt. Although the test runs perfectly through Firefox selenium plugin.

I tried maximizing my window, that also is not working.Please help.

Comment: If the element loads through ajax, you may try waiting for it to be displayed.

Comment: The problem is not with the wait time, the elements that I need to interact with are out of the visible window's span which makes them invisible to the selenium.

Comment: Have you tried scrolling the page through driver or Java script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put an assertElementPresent command for the Authorize button and it started detecting the button and I was able to submit.

Answer (score 0):

Just give a try with below command instead of WebElement click.

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[name='test']"));
new Actions(driver).click(element).perform();
```